# createMaterialTopTabNavigator() has been moved to 'react-navigation-tabs' error react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I have upgraded from react-navigation 3 to react-navigation 4 in one of my old projects, when i try to run i am getting this " createMaterialTopTabNavigator() has been moved to 'react-navigation-tabs' " error. In my other projects the code just works fine. I even deleted node_modules and reinstalled it but still i am getting this error. Can some one please help me sole this ?

This is my App.js

```
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerNavigatorItems, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
{
  Upcoming: { screen: UpcomingScreen },
  Accepted: { screen: AcceptedScreen },
  Ongoing: { screen: OngoingScreen },
  Completed: { screen: CompletedScreen },
},
{
  tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#000000',
      inactiveTintColor: '#000000',
      upperCaseLabel: false,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        paddingTop: calcHeight(2)
      },
      labelStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontFamily: Fonts.LatoRegular,
        fontWeight: 'normal'
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: '#365888',
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
      },
  },
},
);
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "rttDriver",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
      "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
      "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "react": "16.8.3",
  "react-native": "0.59.9",
  "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
  "react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.0.0",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
  "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
  "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
  "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
  "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
  "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.9",
  "react-native-svg": "^9.11.1",
  "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
  "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
  "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
  "react-navigation-drawer": "^1.4.0",
  "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.4",
  "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
 },
 "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
 }
```

I have attached the image below

[image: this is error i am getting]

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you are using react navigatin v4.x.x, in this verion all kind of navigations are moved into separate sub libraries, you please import you material top naigator from react-navigation-tabs

```
import createMaterialTopTabNavigator from 'react-navigation-tabs';
```

Comment: hi @soban, thanks for the reply, i have moved the createMaterialTopTabNavigator separately as i have mentioned in my App.js file.

Comment: nope, that's what i am trying to figure out, why this error

Comment: okay then uninstall your app, then react-native run-ios/android

Comment: and then npm start --reset-cache

Comment: Did you notice that the importing of the module has changed from { create...} to create.. ?

Comment: the error is coming from the `Star.js` file as you can read in the error message. you've only changed your `App.js` file. check all of your files and change your imports

Answer (score 0):

Please read the release notes when upgrading https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases/tag/v4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Just enter

`npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs`

into the terminal and restart it